# Magento REST API Error 500

Tags: rest, magento

I am trying to get product information through Magento REST API; but results an error starting “ [message:protected] => Invalid auth/bad request (got a 500, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
…....................”
No idea why this occurs; can anybody please help me on this ? 
My code follows:

```
$callbackUrl = "http://myhostcom/current_script.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://myhostcom/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" .               urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://myhostcom/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://myhostcom/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://myhostcom/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'xxxxxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
echo '<pre/>';
session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();
    $oauthClient->disableSSLChecks();


if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) { 
    $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1; 
    header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    exit;
} else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {      
    $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
    exit;
} else { 
    $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $resourceUrl = $apiUrl."/products/465"; 
    $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
    $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
    print_r($productsList);
}
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

try below code its working

```
$callbackUrl = "http://myhostcom/current_script.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://myhostcom/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" .               urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://myhostcom/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://myhostcom/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://myhostcom/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'xxxxxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
echo '<pre/>';
session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();
    $oauthClient->disableSSLChecks();


if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) { 
    $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1; 
    header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    exit;
} else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {      
    $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
    exit;
} else { 
    $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $resourceUrl = $apiUrl."/products/465";
    $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array("Content-Type" => "application/json","Accept" => "*/*")); 
    //$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
    $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
    print_r($productsList);
}
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

hope its help you

Comment: adding `"Accept" => "*/*"` to the fetch command did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Specifically what did it was adding the accept header to the fetch line:

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'));
```