# Magento rest api call is not working for my store

Tags: php, magento, rest, magento-1.7

I am newbie to REST API in Magento. I have done all authentication setup with Magento. But while requesting  below url

```
http://store.mystore.net/api/rest/products
```

it returns response as webpage of my store. This all stuff working fine with localhost and other store.

Following is my code:

```
$storeUrl='http://store.mystore.net';
    $params = array(
        'siteUrl' => $storeUrl,
        'requestTokenUrl' => $storeUrl.'/oauth/initiate',
        'accessTokenUrl' => $storeUrl.'/oauth/token',
        'authorizeUrl' => $storeUrl.'/admin/oauth_authorize',

       'consumerKey' => 'myconsumerkey',
       'consumerSecret' => 'myconsumersecret',
        'callbackUrl' => 'mycallbackurl',//Url of callback action below
    );


    // Initiate oAuth consumer with above parameters
    $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($params);
    // Get request token
    $requestToken = $consumer->getRequestToken();

    // Get session
    $_SESSION['requestToken']=serialize($requestToken);
    //$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    // Save serialized request token object in session for later use
    //$session->setRequestToken(serialize($requestToken));
    // Redirect to authorize URL
    $consumer->redirect();
```

callback page code

```
$storeUrl='http://store.mystore.net';
//oAuth parameters
$params = array(
    'siteUrl' => $storeUrl.'/oauth',
    'requestTokenUrl' => $storeUrl.'/oauth/initiate',
    'accessTokenUrl' => $storeUrl.'/oauth/token',

    'consumerKey' => 'myconsumerkey',
    'consumerSecret' => 'mysecretkey'
);


$requestToken = unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
// Initiate oAuth consumer
$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($params);
// Using oAuth parameters and request Token we got, get access token
$acessToken = $consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, $requestToken);
 echo $acessToken;
// Get HTTP client from access token object
$restClient = $acessToken->getHttpClient($params);
// Set REST resource URL?
$restClient->setUri('http://store.mystore.net/api/rest/products');

// configure for request time out
  $restClient->setConfig(array(
//'maxredirects' => 0,
'timeout'      => 3000));
// In Magento it is neccesary to set json or xml headers in order to work
$restClient->setHeaders('Accept', 'application/json');
// Get method
$restClient->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);

//Make REST request
$response = $restClient->request();

// Here we can see that response body contains json list of products

Zend_Debug::dump($response);
```

I have already setup users role and attributes in my admin panel. Help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483875/magento-rest-api-error-500/19677476#19677476

Comment: Thank you shivam. BTW with each request we have to sent header data with consumer key and secret .. how to set it with http header.. ? In your code you automatically sent it or manually ?

Comment: Did you make any change in .htaccess of Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Because your token is rejecting, Please check auth properly.

You can test in Mozila Rest Client.